# Why do my implicitly typed VB.NET variables get typed as Object in an ASPX page but as the type I initialize them to in a VB code file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

If I say:

```
Dim test = "fred"
```

in an ASPX page, the `test` variable is declared as type `Object`. However if I make the same declaration in a VB code file, it is declared as type `String`. Why is this inconsistent? Is there a way to make implicit typing work in ASPX pages as it does in VB code files (and in C# using the `var` keyword)?

Comment: `Option Infer` is `On` in one project and `Off` in the other. In web.config, it's in `<system.codedom> <compilers><compiler language="vb... /optionInfer+..."/>`. You can set it in the Project's Properties or or Visual Studio configuration.

Comment: It appears to be on in both of my projects; it seems to be turning itself off somehow when I have VB code embedded in an ASPX page (as opposed to in a VB file).

Comment: Someone explicitly set it to `Off` in `Global.asax.vb`?

Comment: There is no `Global.asax.vb` from what I can tell; searching the solution for `Option Infer` turns up nothing.

Comment: If I add `<%@ Option Infer On %>` to the top of my ASPX page (right below the `@Page` directive), this still doesn't cause the variables to be declared as their appropriate types; they're still declared as `Object`...